# Can't get [ALAsset thumbnail] for picture, but works for video

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I 'm trying to display the thumbnail for a picture or video my app takes. It works perfectly for video but for a picture it simply doesn't show anything. This is the code I used:

```
[assetImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]]];
```

I also tried this as an alternative but also nothing:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[assetRepresentation fullScreenImage]];
[assetImageView setImage:image];
```

Any ideas what may be going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem wasn't on this method, it was before. I wasn't retaining the object asset so it got lost before reaching this line. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please show us the result of `NSLog(@"asset:%@", asset)` when the problem occurs? Your 1st code works fine under my environment.